# Unix genius - remove "." from a bunch of filenames?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I have an amount of files, somewhat inexplicably, but due to extenuating circumstances, receive a ". " (period AND space) appended to the front of the filename.

I would like to write a bash script to remove this, but I don't really know where to start.

I can retrieve a list of all the affected files by

```
find dir -name ".*"
```

But that's about all I know. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Now you do know that in Linux/Unix it is completely normal to have files with a "." in front of them, right?  That means they are "hidden".  For instance, if you enter "ls -a" in your home (~) directory, you'll see a whole lot of hidden directories and such.

Comment: Right, they're not supposed to be :P

Comment: If you do a lot of this sort of thing, I wrote a very Perl program many years ago that lets you do mass renaming using a substitution:  http://pastebin.com/BZ3MzMcn   (For example:  `regmv * s/foo/bar/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find dir -type f -regex ".*/[.] .*" -exec rename ". " "" {} \;
```

Find everything within dir where the name matches the regular expression `".*/[.] .*"` - "Anything, slash, dot, space, anything"

For each found file, execute: `rename ". " "" filename` which changes ". " to "" in the file called `filename`

Comment: I can't get this command to work. I tried running just the "find dir -name "[.] .*" and turned up nothing, whereas using ".*" turned up all the affected files. Then I tried that while also inserting the rest of the command, and it gave me a repeated Syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near ".". Also, could you explain what exactly rename is doing? I'm trying to learn.

Comment: To find out more about `rename` type `man rename` in a terminal. This is the `rename` manual (hence the `man`) and is generally the first place to look for information about a command.

Comment: Use this new form of find instead.

Comment: Again, simply find dir -regex "^[.] .*" turns up nothing.

Comment: I always avoid recommending `rename` in Linux, because I've seen three different implementations of the command in different distros, all of which take different options. Since the question is also tagged [tag:unix], wouldn't it be better to suggest a solution that is portable? Also, if you're using find with rename, which takes multiple filenames as its trailing options, consider replacing `\;` with `+`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Perl script version of `rename`:

```
find dir -name '. *' -exec rename 's/^. //' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for fn in \.\ *; do mv -T "$fn" "${fn:2}"; done
```

The `-T` is for safety, i.e., treat "${fn:2}" as file instead of directory.

(Tested in bash)

Comment: This is the way to solve this, though you don't need to escape the dot. `.\ *` will be sufficient to match the files described in the question; dots are not special characters in bash's Pathname Expansion.